# How to evaluate this limit and its convergence? $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to evaluate this limit
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}$$
 and its convergence?

I tried ratio test, root test, Raabe's test. However, I'm not getting anywhere. Can you please help me? Thank you

Comment: For $n > 4$, $\dfrac1{n\sqrt[n]{n}} > \dfrac1{n\log\,n}$. It can be shown through other means that $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n\log\,n}$ is divergent, so...

Comment: @J.M. I wonder why you prefer $\sqrt[n]{n}\lt\log n$ for every $n\gt4$ to $\sqrt[n]{n}\lt2$ for every $n\geqslant1$...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300243/does-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n-sqrtnn-converge)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For $n$ sufficiently large, $\root n\of n<2$; so, 
$${1\over n\,\root n\of n}>{1\over 2n}$$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Since the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty {1\over 2n}$ diverges (it is essentially the harmonic series), it follows from the Comparison test that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  {1\over n\,\root n\of n}$ diverges.

Comment: *For $n$ sufficiently large*... Read: *For every $n\geqslant1$*.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: search an equivalent of $\sqrt[n]{n}$ as $n$ goes to $+\infty$ and use the [Limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).