# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Does the following series converge? $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}$$

As $$\frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}=\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}},$$
I was thinking that you may consider this as a p-series with $p>1$. But I'm not sure if this is correct, as with p-series, p is a fixed number, right ? On the other hand, $1+\frac{1}{n}>1$ for all $n$. Any hints ?

Comment: you could use root test or ratio test to get a hint.

Comment: did you miss n square root in the base?

Comment: If the series is $\sum 1/n\sqrt{n}$ as written, it *is* a $p$ series with $p=3/2$ so converges. But after "As...I was thinking" it looks like the series is different. Was it supposed to be $\sum 1/(n \cdot n^(1/n))$ for the problem?

Comment: sorry to be confusing, fixed it, it's about this series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}$

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Hint:** $\sqrt[n]{n}\to1$ when $n\to\infty$ hence, by comparison with the series $\sum\limits_n\frac1n$, this series $______$.

Comment: How do you prove $\sqrt[n]n \to 1$ ?

Comment: Sub-hint: logarithm.

Comment: To prove $n^{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow 1$, first notice that $n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1+\epsilon$ and then use binomial theorem.

Comment: @Did hm... I get $\sqrt[n] n \leq e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}$ for sufficiently large $n$

Comment: No idea how you got that. Try using $\sqrt[n]{n}=\exp((\log n)/n)$ and the fact that $(\log n)/n$ has a known limit when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Did I got my result as  $(\log n)/n \leq 1/ \sqrt n$. Using the squeeze theorem I get the limit is indeed 1. This means the series must diverge right ? Thanks for all the help !

Answer (score 11):

Note that $\sqrt[n]{n}\le 2$. This can be proved by induction, for it is equivalent to $n\le 2^n$.

Thus
$$\frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}\ge \frac{1}{2n}.$$
It follows by Comparison with (half of) the harmonic series that our series diverges.

Comment: Aah, this is a very neat way as well !

Answer (score 6):

Limit comparison test:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]n}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

So that both

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\sqrt[n] n}\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$$

converge or both diverge...

Answer (score 2):

AM-GM gives
$$
\sqrt[n]{n}\leq\frac{1}{n}(n+\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{n-1})=\frac{1}{n}(2n-1)<\frac{1}{n}2n\implies\frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}>\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n}
$$
so
$$
\sum_{n=1}^M\frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}>\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^M\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot
$$