# Showing the series converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is a problem from Apostol's Real Analysis book.
$$\text{Find if  }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\text{ converges or diverges. }$$
I tried to compare with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^p}$ for suitable $p$, but $p>1$ fails always. I tried to show $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^ka_{2^k}$iconverges, where $\displaystyle a_n=n^{-\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$ but again this got too complicated. Can someone give me a proof? Thanks.

Edit : Sorry, I was carried away, because I was thinking it would converge, but the book asked to check for convergence only. I edited it.

Comment: Are you sure that sum converges? Intuitively, I feel like it shouldn't.

Comment: Hmm... See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320144/how-to-prove-sum-frac1n11-n-is-divergent).

Comment: The series clearly diverges. Note that $n^{1/n}$ has limit $1$. So after a while (well, immediately) the $n$-th term is $\gt \frac{1}{2n}$.

Comment: Agreed, it diverges.

Comment: Very good, André Nicolas

Comment: Sorry about this mistake. I apologise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Outline:** One can prove, say by induction, that $2^n\gt n$ for 
every positive integer $n$.

It follows that $n^{1/n}\lt 2$.

From this we can conclude by Comparison that our series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative (and, conceptually, a powerful) way to think about such problems is to use the limit comparison test. Note that $n^{1+1/n} = n\cdot n^{1/n}$. What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}$?