# Why is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over{n^{1+ {1\over\ln \ln n}}}}$ divergent?

Tags: divergent-series

I am just starting to learn Calculus. If anyone could help me that would be very useful. Thanks ahead

From here:
[how to prove $\sum {\frac{1}{n^{1+1/n}}}$ is divergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320144/how-to-prove-sum-frac1n11-n-is-divergent)

I don't really get how to use induction from
$\dfrac{1}{n ^ {1+ \frac{1}{n}}} \lt \dfrac{1}{2n}$

And another one is why 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over {n ^ {1+ {1\over n}}}}$ is divergence and
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over{n^{1+ {1\over \ln n} }}}$ Is not?

I mean
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over{n^{1+ {1\over \ln (\ln n) } }}}$
(Sorry)

Comment: From the last sentence of your post: what makes you think that $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{\ln n}}}$ is not divergent as well? **It is divergent**: you have $n^{\frac{1}{\ln n}} = e^{\frac{1}{\ln n}\cdot \ln n} = e^1 = e$, so $\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{\ln n}}}= \frac{e^{-1}}{n}$, and $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{\ln n}}}=\sum_n \frac{e^{-1}}{n} = \infty$.

Comment: Typesetting note: I do not recommend using `\over` as it can cause a great deal of confusion.  Instead, `\frac{ }{ }` or if you want larger display, `\dfrac{ }{ }` are easier to manipulate.

Comment: and why did $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over{n^{1+ {1\over \ln {\ln (n)}} }}}$ converge?

Comment: Note that your series is undefined at the $n=0$ term, unless you interpret $1/\ln(0)$ as $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edit: we will show that the series with general term $\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{\ln \ln n}}}$ (for $n\geq 3$) is convergent. To do so, we will compare it to the (convergent) series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}$, which is a convergent [Bertrand series](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html).

Rewrite $$
n^{1+\frac{1}{\ln\ln n}} = n\cdot n^{\frac{1}{\ln\ln n}}= n\cdot e^{\frac{\ln n}{\ln\ln n}}
$$
and
$$n(\ln n)^2 = n\cdot e^{2\ln \ln n}$$

We have asymptotically that $\ln \ln n = o\left(\frac{\ln n}{\ln\ln n}\right)$, i.e. for $n$ big enough $\frac{\ln n}{\ln\ln n} > 2\ln \ln n$. This implies $$\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{\ln\ln n}}} < \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}$$ for $n$ big enough, and by comparison that the series $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{\ln \ln n}}}$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that we have

$$n^{1/\log(n)}=e$$

---

**Note that in the original post, the series of interest was $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{\log(n)}}}$**