# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-{(1+1/n)}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having difficulties to determine if the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-{(1+1/n)}}$$

converges or not.

I have rewritten the series in the form

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{(1+1/n)}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt [n]{n}}$$

but I don't know how I should continue form here.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt[n]{n}$ converges and is thus bounded. Then compare to (a multiple of) the harmonic series.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to prove $\sum {\frac{1}{n^{1+1/n}}}$ is divergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320144/how-to-prove-sum-frac1n11-n-is-divergent)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint. Note that $n^{1/n}=e^{\ln n/n}\to 1$.

Comment: So I can say that the given series behaves like the harmonic series which we know is divergent. Is that correct?

Comment: @Elix Yes, it is correct!

Answer (score 2):

Use the limit comparison test with $\;a_n:=\cfrac1{n\sqrt[n]n}\;$ , and $\;b_n:=\cfrac1n\;$ :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

Yet another method. Let $a_n = \frac{1}{n \sqrt[n]{n}}$. Note that $a_n$ is positive and decreasing. Therefore, by Cauchy's Condensation Theorem, one has

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n \sqrt[n]{n}} \sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n\frac{1}{2^n (2^n)^{\frac{1}{2n}}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

which clearly diverges.

If you are not familiar with this test look here: [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}$  because of $1\leq n<2^n$

and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent for $N\to\infty$